# Specify timestamp in ffmpeg video segment command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a continuous RTSP stream coming from a camera over the network.
I want to dump the stream but in video files of length 1 min each.

I an using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:pass@example.com"  -f mp4 -r 12 -s 640x480 -ar 44100 \
-ac 1 -segment_time 60 -segment_format mp4 "out%03d.mp4"
```

The name of the files being created are of the form `out001.mp4`, `out002.mp4`, etc.

I want to include the timestamp (hour and minute) in the name of the file segments eg. `09-30.mp4`, `09-31.mp4`, etc.

If it is mandatory to provide a serial number for the segment, is it possible to get something like `09-30-001.mp4`, `09-31-002`.mp4 ?

Comment: appears there's a (possibly recently added) strftime option https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

Comment: I had tried but was unable to get it. Can you provide me an example with the same command as given in my question ? (I am working on a Windows machine)

Answer (score 18):

Appears you need to add the "-f segment" [parameter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).  Here's an example with strftime as well:

```
 ffmpeg -i your_input -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 -segment_format mp4 out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

segment_time 60 means 60 seconds, strftime 1 means "enable strftime names"

For me this created files with names like this:

`out2015-03-05_10-27-43.mp4`

Comment: Giving an error : 
Invalid segment filename template 'out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4'. 

Ffmpeg version:
N-68694-g7c210c4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers built on Dec 25 2014 22:02:33 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)

Machine:
Windows 7. Feeling the 'strftime' is not working. Do I need to install anything ?

Comment: with `strftime` segment names are based on current machine time, not stream time

Comment: @basin maybe file an ffmpeg feature request for it on its trac? Tell them to consider adding pts and frame_num variables (eval style) @ Sourmya maybe use a more up to date ffmpeg?

Comment: @Soumya, I have the same issue on my macbook with ffmpeg 2.6: seems that for timestamp need and extra component to ffmpeg. I figure it out by using a static build of ffmpeg (I used linux version), and it works.

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 How could you run the linux version of ffmpeg static build on a macbook? I just ran into the same issue, could you explain your solution in details?

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 I found that I just forgot to add "-strftime 1" into parameters. After adding that, it works now!